# JQuery Mobile validation only works for the first fieldset

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

The following code should have all the fields with input required, but when I run it in Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m, after I press the submit button, only the first field (e.g., name) is labeled as "This field is required." I used the example here: `http://www.raymondcamden.com/demos/2012/jul/30/round2/register.html` 
save the `html`, and his local `javascript`, the example code works properly except the "This field is required." is in red. What's wrong here? Please help :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script>    
        $(document).on("pageshow", "#somePage", function() {
            $("#someForm").validate();
        });
    </script>
</head> 

<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="somePage">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <form id="someForm" method="get" action="">
            <fieldset>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input id="name" size="25" class="required"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label">E-Mail</label>
                <input id="email" size="25" class="required"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label">Your comment</label>
                <textarea id="comment" cols="22" class="required"></textarea>   
            </fieldset>         
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>   
        </form>
    </div> <!--content-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have double quotes in label tags that make your html invalid

```
<label">E-Mail</label>
      ^
```

Use `for` attribute in label tags and `name` in `input`s

This being said change

```
<fieldset>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input id="name" size="25" class="required"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label">E-Mail</label>
    <input id="email" size="25" class="required"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label">Your comment</label>
    <textarea id="comment" cols="22" class="required"></textarea>   
</fieldset>
```

to

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input name="name" id="name" size="25" class="required"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" size="25" class="required"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="comment">Your comment</label>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="22" class="required"></textarea>   
</fieldset>
```

**Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4JT2Q/)**

Comment: You are awesome man! What you posted, is it a html thing or is it only for JQM?

Comment: I mean where did you find this usage?